# Rails: Modifying a Model Generated by Scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

How do you modify a model you've generated using modeling?  For example, the model myModel originally had columns a, b and c, but I now want to add column d.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rails 3 and above use the following code :

```
rails generate migration add_fieldname_id_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

---

Rails 2

```
ruby script/generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

This no longer works and returns the following error in Rails 3:

> ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)

Comment: Thanks, would be nice to strike out the non-working combination, though, it confuses a bit... Or may be make some kind of headers (Rails <= 2, Rails >= 3 for example) .

Comment: Thanks Wiseman, just edited to take that into account, is that better?

Answer (score 19):

```
ruby script/generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

this is the shortcut method to do exactly what you want.  if you need more control, or if you have a lot of columns to add, Andrew H's answer will work fine too.

Comment: This used to be the accepted answer but I changed it due to the note in NeoNMD's response about this answer.

Answer (score 13):

The best answer I've found so far is run this from your project root:

```
ruby script/generate migration add_d_column_to_myModel
```

Then edit the new migration file located in db/migration to look something like:

```
  def self.up
    add_column :myModel, :d, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :myModel, :d
  end
```

The last step will be to update your views accordingly.

Answer found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/c9981c94b45b0e53)

Table functions found [here](http://ackbar.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/KirbyBaseAdapter.html)

Comment: Confused--why did you ask the question if you had a good answer? Why not post this in the original question and ask for better solutions?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. One thing I will say, however, is that in some case you can edit the model migration directly. Migrations are great when you have a site in production, but for ongoing development, you often have the luxury of blowing away the DB and starting again.

Comment: I answered my own question for 2 reasons. First, this was the best answer I found, but I'm new to Rails and thought there may be a better way I didn't find.  Second, the Question hadn't been posted on StackOverflow, so I decided to add it.

Comment: I am glad you answered your own question. Lots of people probably have similar questions.