# Rails - Strange Behavior After Adding Field to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a very simple user model. When I first created it, it had three fields `email`, `password_hash`, and `password_salt`.

I recently added a field to that model, in order to allow the user to set a display name, the field being called `display`. I used the method as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530842/rails-modifying-a-model-generated-by-scaffolding/530859#530859). So what I typed into terminal would look like this:

```
script/rails g migration add_display_to_users display:string
```

and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

This worked fine, and after modifying my signup form, I was able to add this data into the database.

In my application layout, I then want to display the user's display name in the header. So, in my application controller, there is a method I call in every controller in order to get the nav bar, called `nav_bar`. In this method I also set a `@user` instance variable, if they are logged in.

Because the  `nav_bar` method is called in the application controller, I can then access it from the application layout. So, I tried to show their email in the header as a test, like so:

```
<% if @user %>
    <div class="ac_button">
        <%= @user.email %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, and displays their email in the header. However, if I change it to

```
 <%= @user.display %>
```

It doesn't display anything.

The strangest part, is if I call `@user.email`, or any other property of the user somewhere in my application controller or layout. It works, and shows their display name. I have no idea why that would make it work, but it does.

For example, if after finding the user in the application controller, I call `@user.email`, it will then show their display name in the layout fine.

```
def nav_bar
    if session[:user_id]
      @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
      @user.email
    end
    # create and return the navbar
end
```

Or if in the layout, I call a property of the user anywhere, it also works.

```
<div class="ac_button">
    <% @user.password_hash %>
    <%= @user.display %>
</div>
```

If anyone can explain this very strange behavior I will be amazed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `display` is an inherited method from `ActiveRecord::Base` so when you create a column called `display` the method `display`and `display=` are created. So you overweite an ActiveRecord method by creating the column `display`. Had this problem earlier,... renamed the column to `display_name` and everything was fine! ;)