# How do I modify a model generated by scaffolding using the new syntax in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails trying to modify a model generated by scaffolding in rails 3. It seems like the **[old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530842/rails-modifying-a-model-generated-by-scaffolding)** way is to use a script/generate command:

```
ruby script/generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string //old way??
```

But when I try the old command it no longer works.

Since you longer use the `ruby script/generate` command to [create a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927841/ruby-error-no-such-file-or-directory-script-generate-loaderrorsyntax%20changed?) I'm assuming the syntax to *modify* a model has changed also. What command should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rails generate migration/model/scaffold`.

Using your example: `rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string`

Comment: thanks. Does that command take any arguments? I am trying to add a Price column to a table called products.

Comment: @akh2103 The example shows arguments, it can take the field name and type, which sounds like what you're asking.